# How to convert a nested data structure to an immutable one in a type-safe way when using Immutable?

Tags: typescript, immutable.js

Immutable comes with the `fromJs` function that transforms a regular nested data structure to an immutable one. My problem is that I can't get it to work nicely with Typescript. This is what I have:

```
type SubData = {
    field1: string;
}

type Data = {
    field0: string;
    subData: SubData[];
};

const arr: Data[] = [];

const list: List<Data> = fromJS(arr);
      ^^^--- compiler error
```

It says

```
Type 'List<Map<keyof Data, string | List<Map<"field1", string>>>>' is not assignable to type 'List<Data>'
```

I tried doing

```
const list: List<Data> = fromJS<Data[]>(arr);
```

but that doesn't help either. How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly define param type for formJs? `fromJS<Data, Data[]>(arr);`

Comment: fromJS has only 1 type parameter and I tried it (see my question).

Comment: Does it actually return a ```List<Data>```? Like, when you remove the type annotation from list and log the result (with data of course), what do you get?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. The example above reproduces the issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can define your list like this

```
type SubData = Immutable.MapOf<{
    field1: string
}>

type Data = Immutable.MapOf<{
    field0: string;
    subData: List<SubData>;
}>;

const arr: Data[] = [];

const list: List<Data> = fromJS(arr)
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=1&pln=3&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgGWAZxgGjgWQIZjYBmUEIAUgMrYBipFlcAvnCWXAOSggCuMeAIwA2AUw4BuAFCSYATzAi4lHgIAiefnAC8cAJIhe-YSIB0+MAHkiAHgSS4D1sBFCAJgEYAXHAxRgAOwBzSSYAPmk5BTh1TR19Q0FRMwIrW3tHImc3AAZvXwDAqUcfFRi8b1QMa2U1DTxQqTCpSQBjCH8MODwoKG8ygG0AXW04Iea2jvghdBgKmesy0JG2BgAKbqgASkkAeh24AD0jgFpTuDbwYFEoOBEe6GlpjBMQAlWAD20l95NAkRhVhw0KU6hxNiYoCJXDwWiJVusWi1sAA3TZfLqIuAAajgyN+-0BmRcHjBm22QA)

---

Edit: By using `fromJS` your array will be an immutable array (`List`) with immutable objects and your type doesn't implies that deep immutability.

A function working with `List<Data>` would be able to do something like:

```
function workingWithDataList(list: List<Data>) {
    // overwriting a property
    return list.forEach(item => item.field0 = "0");
}
```

Comment: This is not a solution. I have my `type`s that I can't change. I need a solution that *uses* my types.

Comment: @AdamArold updated my answer, hope it makes sense now

Comment: I have deeply nested structures and I need deeply nested immutable data structures, it is just not in the example. I still can't use `MapOf` because I have my own type.

Comment: Your type does not represent deeply immutable data

Comment: because it is an example.